# Get SharePoint Office 365 data using Client Id

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am accessing SharePoint online list data using the following code but i get the following error.

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

The web forms application is running in Azure and uses Azure authentication. I would like to use the same credentials for authentication

```
    string siteUrl = "[url]";
    string aadAppId = "[appid]";
    string clientSecret = "[redacted]";
    OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
    ClientContext context = authManager.GetAzureADNativeApplicationAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, aadAppId, appurl, null, AzureEnvironment.Production);
        if (context != null)
            {
             Web web = context.Web;
             context.Load(web);
             context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

I do not want to access the SharePoint using the user credentials.

I have enabled AAD Azure authentication on the web app. The web app authenticates with Azure credentials.

On the CORS setting i have also set the  Domain Url to `"https://domainname.sharepoint.com";`

In the manage permissions section of AAD app I have given the app Permission to read and write sharepoint list and web data.

Comment: In case that secret value you posted was a real one, please be sure to delete it from you app registration immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You example is attempting to retrieve a token as a native client application, which is an app that cannot keep a secret and cannot authenticate by itself. (That's why you'll notice you never use `clientSecret`.)

If you want to use OfficePnP, you can try one of the [`AuthenticationManager.GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/officedevpnp.core.authenticationmanager.getazureadapponlyauthenticatedcontext?view=sharepointpnpcoreonline-2.18.1709.0) methods to authenticate in the app-only context. Note that they all require a certificate for authentication, rather than a secret.

Comment: Thank you Philippe for the reply, but that would require me to install a certificate . Is there any way to achieve it without having to install a certificate.

Comment: Could you share some details on your use case where you can't use a certificate?

Comment: Hi Philiippe, I can't install a certificate as I do not have rights and the admin did not want to install a certificate in  Azure